# How can I replace Redux state?

Tags: redux

I've been trying to replace the entire state object in Redux, but I can't make it work.

```
function loadState(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_STATE':
            return action.state

    default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default loadState;
```

state is an object, and action.state is the object I want the new state to be equal to.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Is this your only reducer? Any change to state in this reducer will only have effects on one part of the state tree.

Comment: Are you sure the dispatched action has a type of 'LOAD_STATE'?

Comment: Are you using `combineReducers`?

Comment: This is the reducer only, and the state is basically the entire store.
It definitely gets that type. I console logged it inside the case.

Comment: And yes, I'm using combineReducers.

Comment: What does your dispatch & action creator code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me, but "I can't make it work" is rather vague. Can you specify what kind of tests you are doing?

Something you might want to try:

```
function reducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_STATE':
            return {...state, newState:action.state}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

you can then display the new state somewhere in your app using

```
{JSON.stringify(state.newState)}
```

This way you can check if the state you pass through arrives correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your solution but it still doesn't change the state.
It's weird cause in Redux dev tools, I can see the previous state, the diff, but the new state remain like the old state.

I really don't get it. Even when I console.log state and action.state in the reducer, those are correct!

Comment: So what's you're saying is that that you tried my solution but you can't the "newState" in your state? Are you sure your action type is correct? Try console logging inside the switch statement

Comment: I tried your code, and I get the same result: the new state equals the previous state.

My action type is definitely an object, and I can see the correct data when I console log the action. By the way the goal of this is to reload an entire new state. I'm using this to allow people to "open a file", that file is basically a JSON of the data redux needs.